# Reverse of Getting a Remainder?

Tags: c++, c

I am taking a number that the user inputs, adding 7, then dividing by 10, and taking the remainder and using that value as my new value. We are also assuming that the input number will ALWAYS be 4 characters long, so for an example the user would input 1234, or 1235, or 9999 etc. It will never be larger, or less than that.

That would look something like this:

```
int num;
printf("Input a number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

num = (num + 7) % 10;

printf("Here is the number after my calculations: %d", num);
```

Now I need to figure out how to do the reverse of that.

How do I get the original number that was input if I am only given the remainder?

Comment: It is modular arithmetic. You can't get the original back.

Comment: You cannot do it, as there are many inputs that map to the same output. If you were provided a domain within which the solution lies, then it would be possible.

Comment: While it may not matter for this question, pick C or C++ and stick with it. The modern languages are not the same and idiomatic answers may differ significantly.

Comment: Uhm, you don't in the generic case. If you know it's always a single digit, you can figure it out, but there's no way to tell if the number of 8, 18, 68 or 11771988 from the answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza - If that weren't the case, almost all of cryptography would be screwed.

Comment: modular arithmetic is great for cryptography for this very reason, you cannot get back to the original without knowing the key/range (and a lot of other technical crap i have no idea how it works).  If you have a key or some set range then you can; however, modulo is a one way street without it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: How do you mean? If you've lost bits, they are lost, can't get them back, no matter what you do.

Comment: We know that it is going to be 4 digits long, does that make any difference for the answer?

Comment: No, 4 digits are too many. You have 9000 different possible input and only 10 possible output, how could you possibly go back?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - That's why I said "if that **weren't** the case".  If you could easily get the original number back then cryptography would be screwed.

Answer (score 4):

There are many inputs that will give the same output (for example, all of 1000, 1010, 1020, 1030 etc will return 7). Therefore, there's no way to restore the four-digit original.

If, on the other hand, you knew that the input were single-digit, you could do the following to restore it:

```
num = (num + 3) % 10;
```

(Adding 3 in modulo-10 arithmetic is the same as subtracting 7.)

There are other circumstances where you could restore the number, but unfortunately in your four-digit general case it's simply not possible.

Comment: That's not really an ANSWER (yes, it is an answer, but it doesn't solve the original question, which is a requirement for a proper answer).

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I think this is as close to an answer as can be reasonably given for the question as stated (I am assuming you're looking at the latest version of the answer).

Comment: I added something. We know that the user is always going to input a 4 digit long number, such as 1234, or 9999, 4321, etc.

Comment: @zacheybuu: Not possible I am afraid. I've edited the answer to reflect the edit to the question.

Comment: @NPE is it possible to break down the 4 digit long number and read each individual digit, then use the modulus for that?

Comment: @zacheybuu: Well, yes, but then it's a different question to the one you're asking. ;-)

Comment: @NPE Will you stick around for a second while I re-edit my question then?

Comment: @zacheybuu: If you're about to ask a different question, please post it as a separate question instead of keeping changing this one.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific about what's been said in the comments: the remainder after dividing by 10 gives you the last (least significant) decimal digit of an input.

Let's assume I get a remainder of 2. If the input was four digits, that means the input was `xyz2`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are each a digit. Any digit I fill in for `x`, `y` and/or `z` gives the correct result the remainder after division.

After that, we're left only with the question of reversing the adding 7 part. That just means that for any given `xyz2`, we need to subtract 7 (and normalize by adding 10, if the result is negative) to get an input that could have produced that result. Every possible value for the `xyz` part will be a valid input that could have produced that result. The result lacks any data to indicate which of these inputs was used to produce this particular result.