# Individual Digits out of a Long Integer?

Tags: c

A user will input a 4 digit long number. The number will always be 4 digits long. I need to figure out a way to break down the 4 digit long number, and read each individual digit. Once I have each individual digit I am going to perform this calculation on it:

```
int num;
num = (num + 7) % 10
```

I will add 7, then dividing by 10, and taking the remainder and using that value as my new value. I will then print out the remainders.

How do I break down the 4 digit long number, and use the individual digits to perform my calculation?

Additionally, I have to be able to reverse the process. If I am only given the remainder, how do I print out what the original number was?

Comment: You mean you will do that for each digit, from low/high to high/low, right?

Comment: Do not see this as a true duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773702/reverse-of-getting-a-remainder as that one performs the remainder in the input number and this one performs the same on each digit of the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number; //suppose number is 7653
...

int n = number;         //n = 7653
int lastDigit = n%10;   //3
n/=10;                  //n = 765
int thirdDigit = n%10;  //5
n/=10;                  //n = 76
int secondDidit = n%10; //6
n/=10;                  //n = 7
int firstDigit = n;     //7
```

This can obviously be done in a loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive routine will handle 4 digits as well as up to 9 digits for a 32-bit `unsigned`.

```
unsigned R7(unsigned x) {
  unsigned y = 0;
  if (x >= 10) {
    y = R7(x / 10) * 10;
  }
  y += (x % 10 + 7) % 10;
  return y;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%04u\n", R7(1));
  printf("%04u\n", R7(12));
  printf("%04u\n", R7(123));
  printf("%04u\n", R7(4321));
  printf("%04u\n", R7(987654321));
  return 0;
}

// Output
0008
0089
0890
1098
654321098
```

To reverse the process, add 3 rather than 7.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to read the number as a string and then pass each character to a 2-char string getting the numeric value with `atoi`. It can then handle any number of digits input by limiting the conversion to the first four characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;      /* pointer to use with getline ()   */
    ssize_t read = 0;       /* number of characters read        */
    size_t n = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    char numstr[] = "a";    /* array to hold each char of input */
    int num = 0;            /* number result                    */

    printf ("\nEnter a 4-digit number (or ctrl+d to quit)\n");

    while (printf ("\n input: ") && (read = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) {

        if (read > 4) {
            for (cnt = 0; cnt < 4; cnt++) {
                numstr[0] = line[cnt];
                num = (atoi (numstr) + 7) % 10;
                printf ("    ( %d + 7 ) %% 10 = %d\n", atoi (numstr), num);
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** further input validation (e.g. confirming each char entered is a digit) is left as an exercise. This was just to show the mechanics of processing the input as a string.

**output:**

```
./bin/digits

Enter a 4-digit number (or ctrl+d to quit)

input: 1234
    ( 1 + 7 ) % 10 = 8
    ( 2 + 7 ) % 10 = 9
    ( 3 + 7 ) % 10 = 0
    ( 4 + 7 ) % 10 = 1

input: 23456
    ( 2 + 7 ) % 10 = 9
    ( 3 + 7 ) % 10 = 0
    ( 4 + 7 ) % 10 = 1
    ( 5 + 7 ) % 10 = 2
```

Comment: It was intentional to show it would only operate on the first 4-characters of the input.